# Function taking Vectors and Scalars

Tags: julia

I have a function that takes a vector

```
function foo(x::Vector{Int64})
    x
end
```

How can I make it work also for scalars (i.e. turn them into one-element vectors)?

I know that I can do this:

```
foo(x::Int64) = foo([x])
```

but this stops being cool when there are more arguments, because you're writing multiple methods to achieve only one thing.

I think I something like `foo(x::Union{Int64, Vector{Int64}})`, but I don't know where or how it works or if it is the right thing to do.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If it's just the first argument that should be converted, you can define `foo(x::Number, args...) = foo([x], args...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a helper function which either converts or does nothing. Then the main function can accept any combination:

```
_vec(x::Number) = [x]
_vec(x::AbstractVector) = x

function f(x, y, z)  # could specify ::Union{Number, AbstractVector}
  xv = _vec(x)
  yv = _vec(y)
  ...
end
```

The `...` could do the actual work, or could call `f(xv, yv, zv)` where another method `f(x::AbstractVector, y::AbstractVector, z::AbstractVector)` does the work --- whichever seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The main time this comes up is if the version of your function for vectors does the same thing for all of it's elements. In this case, what you want to do is define `f(x::Int)`, and use broadcasting `f.([1,2,3])` for the vector case.

Comment: I get the impression that this is the opposite, that the base case is a vector, and the scalar is a special case.

Comment: Hm, this is not the answer. Sorry.